# Inconsistent absolute positioning within inline elements between browsers

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am currently struggling with some differences between Firefox and Chrome, which show different behaviour when placing an absolutely positioned element within a relatively positioned element that has `display:inline;`.

In Chrome, the following example puts the "Foo" label on top of the right bottom side of the text-input, and in Firefox, the "Foo" label is placed on top of the "Example" text above the input box.

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.relative-box {
  position: relative;
}
.relative-box::after {
  content: "Foo";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background: #AAA;
}
input[type="text"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 260px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <label class="container">
    <span class="relative-box">
      Example:
      <input type="text"/>
      </span>
  </label>
</div>
```

I am curious to know if there is any way to keep the exact same functionality, including the usage of `<label>`, while also getting consistent rendering of the "Foo" text.

Preferably I would like to have a solution that does not involve changing `display:inline;` to anything else, because for my applications, that would also have additional unwanted effects.

PS: Note that this is a minimal working example. The fact this looks very user-unfriendly is because a lot of styling is not applied to this example.

Comment: Here's the bug report. Looks like it's been out there for 11 years. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=489100

Comment: @cjc damn, that's an old bug... I guess I'll not wait for a fix of that then. I guess I'll have to take a look at fixing it with `inline-block` then.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox keeps the size of each box unique. Therefore, it does not make the relative box the same size as the input.

If you use display: block in the "relative-box" div, it will fit the size of your children in firefox. So the behavior will be the same in both.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using anything like normalize.css? It could help with the inconsistencies you are seeing. Here is the link to more information - http://nicolasgallagher.com/about-normalize-css/

Some of the advantages of the normalize.css file are:
  Preserve useful browser defaults rather than erasing them.
  Normalize styles for a wide range of HTML elements.
  Correct bugs and common browser inconsistencies.
  Improve usability with subtle improvements.

Comment: While that may be helpful in general, it doesn't seem to contain any styles that help with this particular rendering difference. https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css